# Me da error al usar tildes en Visual Studio Community 2022

Tags: python, visual-studio, utf-8, tildes

Al colocar tildes y ejecutar el código me suelta error. Por ejemplo:

`print ("Buenos días.")`

Y ejecutarlo (no importa si es depurando o no), me sale:

> SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xed in position 8: invalid continuation byte

He visto cómo se soluciona en Visual Studio Code, pero no en el caso de Visual Studio Community 2022.

Cabe destacar que me pasa solo con proyectos creados en Python, en proyectos creados en C# no me da error al colocar tildes.

Comment: ¿Qué versión de Python utilizas? En 3.9 es un problema que ha sido reportado, tal vez intenta cambiar de versión.

Answer (score 0):

Yo también estoy empezando a practicar Python con el IDE Visual Studio Community 2022 (a fecha de hoy la versión 17.7) bajo Windows 11.
La versión Python que tengo instalada es la 3.9 (64-bit)

Buscando una solución para que la salida en castellano (con ñ, tiles, etc...) por consola no de el error: "SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte ..."

Encontré esta en StackOverflow (en inglés):

```
# coding: latin1
print ("Buenos días)
```

Y a mí me funciona.

Al iniciar, VS Commnunity 2022 me abre una consola con el resultado:

> Buenos días

No sé si le será de utilidad.